# Unable to Build Release APK - React Native/Gradle

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, nvm

I'm trying to build a release APK from command line of a react-native project. This has worked multiple times in the past (app is already in App Store/Play Store), but started failing today with a new error.

The command I'm running is simply

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
>   You are currently running io.js v8.1.0.
>   React Native runs on Node 8.3 or newer. There are several ways to
>    upgrade Node.js depending on your preference.
>    nvm:       nvm install 8.3 --reinstall-packages-from=node
>    Homebrew:  brew update && brew upgrade node
>    Installer: download from https://nodejs.org/
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
>   Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Note that I am using `nvm` for handling node version, and running `node -v` returns

> v8.3.0

I had to hot-swap to 8.1.0 to build for a different project, using

```
nvm alias default 8.1.0
nvm use 8.1.0
```

But swapping back to 8.3.0 seems to have missed something. From what I can tell, `io.js` and `node.js` are the same thing after version 4, but I can't find anything on how to fix this.

Note: I've tried the suggestion in the error message, `nvm install 8.3 --reinstall-packages-from=node`, but that didn't do anything. I've also tried a `./gradlew clean`, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution is to run

```
nvm uninstall 8.1.0
```

After running

```
nvm alias default 8.3.0
nvm use 8.3.0
```

`nvm` was simply not letting go of 8.1, even though I told it to use `8.3`, closed terminal, restarted computer, etc.

Might have to re-install `8.1.0` at a later date if `8.3.0` doesn't work for other project, but yeah... Weird error.